# One to many relationship without navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int MyEntityID { get; set; }
    public int Foo { get; set; }


    public ICollection<MyEntityDetail> MyEntityDetails { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntityDetail
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int PK { get; set; } // this will be the MyEntityID from MyEntity
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int OtherPK { get; set; } // this will be manually set
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntityContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyEntityDetail> MyEntityDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

i think above code explains what im trying to achieve with entity framework code first 4.2
note that MyEntityDetail doesnt contain a navigation property to MyEntity. how could i associate MyEntityID from MyEntity to PK from MyEntityDetail?? if i have to i can add MyEntity navigation property to MyEntityDetail class but i dont want to use extra memory for a property i never access. and this type of entites will be used 100+ times in my project. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that. In case of one-to-one relationship it is possible to be FK for PK, but in one-to-many relationship it is not possible since child table(MyEntityDetail table)'s PK is unique value it can't be duplicated

Comment: ive added MyEntity property to MyEntityDetail class and added this code to OnModelCreating            modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityDetail>().HasRequired(d => d.MyEntity).WithMany(d => d.MyEntityDetails).HasForeignKey(d => d.PK);                                                               now it saves related detail records, but when it comes reading, MyEntityDetails is always null.. by the way, there is composite key, so PK doesnt need to be unique so duplicate entries wont be problem as soon as OtherPK does make difference